# MongoDB: blocked queries during write operation in a replica set

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am using MongoDB (3.0) with a replica set of 3 servers. I experience very slow queries since a week and I have tried to find out what was wrong on my servers.

By using the `db.currentOp()` command I can see that queries are sometimes blocked on the secondaries when a "replication worker" is running. All the queries are waiting for lock (`"waitingForLock" : true`) and it seems that the replication worker has taken this lock and is running since several minutes (seems pretty long).

To be more specific about my user case, I have multiple databases in the replica set, all these database containing the same collections but not the same amount of data (I use one database per client).

I use WiredTiger as a storage engine that normally (as the doc claims) do not use global locks. So I was expecting that queries on the specific collection to be slow if this collection is updated, but I was not expecting all the queries to be slow or blocked.

Does anyone experienced the same issue? Is there some limitation with MongoDB when read are performed when processes write in the database?

Furthermore, is there a way to tell MongoDB that I don't care about consistency for read operations (in order to avoid locks)?

Thanks.

**Update :**

By restarting the servers the problems disappeared. It seems that memory and cpu usage was growing (but was still very low) that this lead to slow replication process which hold a lock and prevent queries execution.

I still don't understand why the we have the problem on this database. Maybe version 3.0.9 has a bug (I will upgrade to 3.0.12). Still it takes one month to the database to be very slow and only a restart of all the servers solve the problem. Our workload is mainly writes (with findAndModify). Does anyone know about a bug in Mongo where intensive write leads to performance decreasing over the time ?

Comment: if you are okay with less consistent results then probably you can set quorum value to 'one'. This will serve reads from a node and won't validate it with other replicas. This will help to reduce your problem up to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am not sure I understand what you mean. How do you change this quorum setting for reads (I'm new to mongodb)?

Comment: @vespasien  Did you find a solution for this problem ?

Comment: nope, we still avoid to make too much write during read operations.